# Error Correction : He being the eldest son his father expects him to take care of several things besides his regular studies

Tags: pronouns, exam-questions

> He being the eldest son (A)/  his father expects him to take care of several things(B)/ besides his regular studies.(C)

Is the above sentence correct ? Usually I have heard/read sentences which have possessive form being used  before *being* e.g.

> He turns a blind eye to my being late every day.

So I think the *he* used in first part is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is correct.

The version with a possessive, *his being...*, is employed when the *-ing* clause acts as a 'gerund', in the same contexts where a noun phrase may occur. In your second example, for instance, the clause *my being late every day* is the object of the preposition *to*; you might equivalently say "He turns a blind eye to my tardiness." The possessive form *his* acts as a determiner and marks the *-ing* form as 'nouny'.

In your first sentence, however, the *-ing* clause is an 'absolute', a syntactic supplement which is not integrated into the syntax of the main clause. The verb *BE* is cast in the *-ing* form to mark the clause as subordinate to the main clause, but in other respects the *-ing* clause is structured like an independent clause: its subject takes subject form.

You should note, by the way, that both the possessive and the subject forms alternate with an object form:

> He turns a blind eye to **me** being late every day.
>   **Him** being the eldest son, his father expects him...

With gerund clauses, the object form is common in colloquial use, but traditionally deprecated in formal use. Absolutes are quite formal and are so rare in colloquial use that they tend to sound odd with **any** form of pronominal subject. I recommend that in your own writing you restrict yourself to nominal subjects, where the object/subject contrast does not exist.

> **Rob** being the eldest son, his father expects him...